# Why does binary serialization byte layout differ on iOS and Android

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, mono

In Unity3d, I use binary serialization with [Serializable] decorators to create snapshots of my game world state. Then to compare equality of different world states I count a hash from the byte array created by BinaryFormatter.

On different platforms, namely iOS and Android, the serializer produces different byte layouts for the same game state. Both are valid and deserialize to the same state. However, as the layout differs, I get different hashes for the same state on different platforms. Why do the layouts differ? Does reflection go through object fields in different order on different platforms? Is there a workaround to get same layouts on different platforms using BinaryFormatter?

As a quick fix I implemented a light old-school binary serialization with interfaces and hand-tunable serialization order, but in the long run it is not as easily maintainable as automated serialization.

Comment: Could it be differences in bigendian/littleendian format?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Excellent idea, I'll need to run some tests to check that.